# L293D motor driver resistor network confusion

Tags: motordriver, schematic, adafruit

I've been trying to modify the original Adafruit V1 L293D motor driver, but have run into a bit of a roadblock when reading its [schematic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Motor-Shield-v1/master/mshieldv12schem.png). The text labelling the resistor network has stacked and become unreadable:

[image: 1]

I've scoured google looking for more readable images to no avail, and also tried to download the `.sch` and `.brd` files provided on its GitHub page, however am unable to run these on KiCad.

As of now, I've inferred it as a bussed 9-pin 10k resistor network connected to ground, but would really appreciate some confirmation that I'm not a complete idiot. My schematic is as seen below.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like thte schematic indicates that the resistor pack can be any value between 10K and 100K.  Likewise, the resistor in series withthe Power LED can be 1K to 2K.